# How to I restore deleted UIKit.framework and Foundation.framework and others

Tags: xcode, frameworks, uikit, foundation

I deleted UIKit.framework and Foundation.framework in an xcode project by accident. I can't find the framework in the target information (general tab) link libraries section.

How could I add them to the project again as I'm now getting many errors!

Answer (score 2):

Project > Edit Active Target > General tab, click the + button to add frameworks.